# Glide - How to apply Circular Crop to Error image?

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-glide

I can successfully load an image with glide into an Image View and crop it with the `.circularCrop()` method.

```
Glide.with(this)
     .load("https://i.imgur.com/QjQGiPj.jpeg")
     .circleCrop()
     .into(imageView);
```

I'm trying to add an error placeholder `Drawable` if the url loaded fails with `.error(R.drawable.placeholder)`.

The problem with this is that the error placeholder does not crop the error image with Circle crop.

**Successful load:**

[image]

**Unsuccessful load:**

[image]

**How do I also apply the `.circleCrop()` to the error placeholder image?**

I've tried adding a circular drawable background to the `ImageView`, but that doesn't work

`bgr_circular`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:color="@color/white"/>
    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@color/defaultHintColor"/>
</shape>
```

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_view"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bgr_circular"/>
```

**Code for testing:**

```
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.10.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.10.0'
```

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.image_view);
        Button button = findViewById(R.id.btn_test);
        button.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            Glide.with(this)
                    .load("https://i.imgur.com/QjQGiPj.jpe") //Test with incorrect url
                    .circleCrop()
                    .error(R.drawable.placeholder)
                    .into(imageView);
        });
    }

}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_test"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Load Image"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_view"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bgr_circular"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:color="@color/white"/>
    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@color/defaultHintColor"/>
</shape>
```

**Edit 1:__________________________________________________________**

I've tried using one of the older solutions in Glide's github

https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/1212#issuecomment-221751860

But this doesn't quite work.

```
Bitmap placeholder = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.placeholder);
RoundedBitmapDrawable circularBitmapDrawable = RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory.create(this.getResources(), placeholder);
        circularBitmapDrawable.setCircular(true);

        
Glide.with(this)
     .load("https://i.imgur.com/QjQGiPj.jpe")
     .circleCrop()
     .error(circularBitmapDrawable)
     .into(imageView);
```

[image]

Comment: For a easy workaround you can have  a Circular error image . Or for even better You can use `CircularImageView`. `CircularImageView` is better option i think because right now your borders also getting overlapped by image

Comment: Is ```CircularImageView``` part of the material library? I'm currently using ```com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0``` and can't find it in XML. Or is it a 3rd party library?

Comment: It's not part of material lib as far as i know its a custom `ImageView` so a 3rd party lib . for the error drawable if you are showing it on a circular shape atleast use a square image for better scale .

Comment: The ```CircleImageView``` library works perfectly loading the error placeholder with glide. It even adds the border perfectly so I don't even need my custom drawable class anymore. Thanks for the recommendation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use RoundedBitmapDrawable for circular images with Glide. No custom ImageView is required

```
 Glide.with(context).load(url).asBitmap().centerCrop().into(new BitmapImageViewTarget(imageView) {
    @Override
    protected void setResource(Bitmap resource) {
        RoundedBitmapDrawable circularBitmapDrawable =
                RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory.create(context.getResources(), resource);
        circularBitmapDrawable.setCircular(true);
        imageView.setImageDrawable(circularBitmapDrawable);
    }
});
```

Comment: which Glide version is that? I don't have a ```.asBitmap() method```. https://i.imgur.com/UDec3NQ.png

Comment: Nevermind. The ```.asBitmap()``` method has to be used before ```.load()``` to appear.

Comment: it's 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'  yes , you have to write asBitmap() after contex

Comment: my question is about circle cropping the error placeholder image. This doesn't do that?

Comment: Hahah.. @AliSalehi was in too much of a hurry to post an answer that he forgot the read the question. BTW Dave were you able to solve this?